# collector.on 'collect' event with button rows, discord js buttons

Tags: javascript, button, discord, rows

I'm using button rows for the first time and I use

This

```js
collector.on('collect', Button => {
        ...
});
```

For my buttons collector (on message with 3 rows of buttons), as I did before

But I suppose it should look somewhat different because it runs but doesnt recognize the button

Comment: (node:15368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked, it fires the "interactionCreate" event. So to filter the slash commands and the message components you should use:

```
client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if (interaction.type == "APPLICATION_COMMAND") {
        client.emit("slashCommand", interaction)
    }
    else if (interaction.type == "MESSAGE_COMPONENT") {
        client.emit("clickButton", interaction)
    }
}
```

And then you can just create that 2 collectors like this:

```
client.on("slashCommand", SlashCommand => {
    //your code
})

client.on("clickButton", Button => {
    //your code
})
```